# AWS Python lambda scripts to remove special character from the JSON key name

Tags: python, json, aws-lambda

I am trying to remove special characters (like forward slash, $, etc.) from JSON key name (not from JSON value). I have written a Python script to convert single line JSON to break my each record (meaning each JSON payload should start from the new line). I want to include the logic of removing/renaming special character in this Python script. My idea is to basically use regex and ignore everything except character and number `("[^a-zA-Z0-9]")` but I am not able to put this logic in the code as it needs to be only done for the key/field and not for the value.

Python:

```
import json
import boto3
import base64
import re

output = []

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    for record in event['records']:
        payload = base64.b64decode(record['data']).decode('utf-8')
        print('payload:', payload)
        
        row_w_newline = payload + "\n"
        print('row_w_newline type:', type(row_w_newline))
        row_w_newline = base64.b64encode(row_w_newline.encode('utf-8'))
        
        output_record = {
            'recordId': record['recordId'],
            'result': 'Ok',
            'data': row_w_newline
        }
        output.append(output_record)

    print('Processed {} records.'.format(len(event['records'])))
    
    return {'records': output}
```

Including sample JSON:

```
  "ProductFields": {
                "StandardsArn": "arn:aws:securityhub:::standards/aws-foundational-security-best-practices/v/1.0.0",               
                "RelatedAWSResources:0/name": "securityhub-ec2-instance-managed-by-ssm-dc0c9f18",
                "RelatedAWSResources:0/type": "AWS::Config::ConfigRule",
                "StandardsControlArn": "arn:aws:securityhub:us-east-1:492931852779:control/aws-foundational-security-best-practices/v/1.0.0/SSM.1",
                "aws/securityhub/ProductName": "Security Hub",
                "aws/securityhub/CompanyName": "AWS"
                }
```

Something like this:

```
      Input :
        "RelatedAWSResources:0/name": "securityhub-ec2-instance-managed-by-ssm-dc0c9f18",
        "RelatedAWSResources:0/type": "AWS::Config::ConfigRule",               
        "aws/securityhub/ProductName": "Security Hub",
        "aws/securityhub/CompanyName": "AWS"
        Output:              
        "RelatedAWSResources0name": "securityhub-ec2-instance-managed-by-ssm-dc0c9f18",
        "RelatedAWSResources0type": "AWS::Config::ConfigRule",               
        "awssecurityhubProductName": "Security Hub",
        "awssecurityhubCompanyName": "AWS"
```

Complete JSON:

```json
{
    "version": "0", 
    "id": "e517d9a2-84ed-a2fb-fce7-bf5ff02b271b", 
    "detail-type": "Security Hub Findings - Imported", 
    "source": "aws.securityhub", 
    "account": "220307202362", 
    "time": "2021-10-19T07:26:54Z", 
    "region": "us-west-2", 
    "resources": [
        "arn:aws:securityhub:us-west-2::product/aws/securityhub/arn:aws:securityhub:us-west-2:220307202362:subscription/cis-aws-foundations-benchmark/v/1.2.0/1.1/finding/c5e2448c-a877-428e-adfe-4f21ab0b2d23"
    ], 
    "detail": {
        "findings": [
            {
                "ProductArn": "arn:aws:securityhub:us-west-2::product/aws/securityhub", 
                "Types": [
                    "Software and Configuration Checks/Industry and Regulatory Standards/CIS AWS Foundations Benchmark"
                ], 
                "Description": "The \"root\" account has unrestricted access to all resources in the AWS account. It is highly recommended that the use of this account be avoided.", 
                "Compliance": {
                    "Status": "FAILED", 
                    "StatusReasons": [
                        {
                            "Description": "Multi-region CloudTrail with the required configuration does not exist in the account.", 
                            "ReasonCode": "CLOUDTRAIL_MULTI_REGION_NOT_PRESENT"
                        }
                    ]
                }, 
                "ProductName": "Security Hub", 
                "FirstObservedAt": "2021-09-27T19:34:26.016Z", 
                "CreatedAt": "2021-09-27T19:34:26.016Z", 
                "LastObservedAt": "2021-10-19T07:26:50.588Z", 
                "CompanyName": "AWS", 
                "FindingProviderFields": {
                    "Types": [
                        "Software and Configuration Checks/Industry and Regulatory Standards/CIS AWS Foundations Benchmark"
                    ], 
                    "Severity": {
                        "Normalized": 30, 
                        "Label": "LOW", 
                        "Product": 30, 
                        "Original": "LOW"
                    }
                }, 
                "ProductFields": {
                    "StandardsGuideArn": "arn:aws:securityhub:::ruleset/cis-aws-foundations-benchmark/v/1.2.0", 
                    "StandardsGuideSubscriptionArn": "arn:aws:securityhub:us-west-2:220307202362:subscription/cis-aws-foundations-benchmark/v/1.2.0", 
                    "RuleId": "1.1", 
                    "RecommendationUrl": "https://docs.aws.amazon.com/console/securityhub/standards-cis-1.1/remediation", 
                    "StandardsControlArn": "arn:aws:securityhub:us-west-2:220307202362:control/cis-aws-foundations-benchmark/v/1.2.0/1.1", 
                    "aws/securityhub/ProductName": "Security Hub", 
                    "aws/securityhub/CompanyName": "AWS", 
                    "aws/securityhub/annotation": "Multi region CloudTrail with the required configuration does not exist in the account", 
                    "Resources:0/Id": "arn:aws:iam::220307202362:root", 
                    "aws/securityhub/FindingId": "arn:aws:securityhub:us-west-2::product/aws/securityhub/arn:aws:securityhub:us-west-2:220307202362:subscription/cis-aws-foundations-benchmark/v/1.2.0/1.1/finding/c5e2448c-a877-428e-adfe-4f21ab0b2d23"
                }, 
                "Remediation": {
                    "Recommendation": {
                        "Text": "For directions on how to fix this issue, consult the AWS Security Hub CIS documentation.", 
                        "Url": "https://docs.aws.amazon.com/console/securityhub/standards-cis-1.1/remediation"
                    }
                }, 
                "SchemaVersion": "2018-10-08", 
                "GeneratorId": "arn:aws:securityhub:::ruleset/cis-aws-foundations-benchmark/v/1.2.0/rule/1.1", 
                "RecordState": "ACTIVE", 
                "Title": "1.1 Avoid the use of the \"root\" account", 
                "Workflow": {
                    "Status": "NEW"
                }, 
                "Severity": {
                    "Normalized": 30, 
                    "Label": "LOW", 
                    "Product": 30, 
                    "Original": "LOW"
                }, 
                "UpdatedAt": "2021-10-19T07:26:47.032Z", 
                "WorkflowState": "NEW", 
                "AwsAccountId": "220307202362", 
                "Region": "us-west-2", 
                "Id": "arn:aws:securityhub:us-west-2:220307202362:subscription/cis-aws-foundations-benchmark/v/1.2.0/1.1/finding/c5e2448c-a877-428e-adfe-4f21ab0b2d23", 
                "Resources": [
                    {
                        "Partition": "aws", 
                        "Type": "AwsAccount", 
                        "Region": "us-west-2", 
                        "Id": "AWS::::Account:220307202362"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: if I'm understanding correctly you don't need regex for this. you can just strip all punctuation from the string with Python.

Comment: Can you please some sample code in above function ?

Answer (score 0):

```
import json
import base64

json_string= '{"Relate:0/name": "securityhub-ec2-instance-managed-by-ssm-dc0c9f18","RelatedAWSResources:0/type": "AWS::Config::ConfigRule","aws/securityhub/ProductName": "Security Hub","aws/securityhub/CompanyName": "AWS"}'

json_dict = json.loads(json_string)
print(json_dict.keys())
new_dict = {}
for key in json_dict.keys():
    new_dict[base64.b64encode(key.encode('utf-8'))]= json_dict[key]
print(new_dict)
```

here you can see i have converted keys to base64, in that same place you could call a function to replace special characters.

Comment: Posting complete json it is not able to print all the keys using above code :

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest creating a helper function that strips all punctuation from a string. I'm actually using something similar in a project of mine.

```py
import string
from typing import Optional, Iterable, Union


delete_dict = {sp_character: '' for sp_character in string.punctuation}

PUNCT_TABLE = str.maketrans(delete_dict)


def strip_punctuation(s: str,
                      exclude_chars: Optional[Union[str, Iterable]] = None) -> str:
    """
    Remove punctuation and spaces from a string.

    If `exclude_chars` is passed, certain characters will not be removed
    from the string.

    """
    punct_table = PUNCT_TABLE.copy()
    if exclude_chars:
        for char in exclude_chars:
            punct_table.pop(ord(char), None)

    # Next, remove the desired punctuation from the string
    return s.translate(punct_table)
```

Usage:

```py
cleaned_keys = {'RelatedAWSResources:0/name': 'RelatedAWSResources0name',
                'RelatedAWSResources:0/@!type#$%': 'RelatedAWSResources0type',
                'aws/securityhub/ProductName': 'awssecurityhubProductName',
                'aws/securityhub/CompanyName': 'awssecurityhubCompanyName'}

for key, expected_key in cleaned_keys.items():
    actual_key = strip_punctuation(key)
    assert actual_key == expected_key, f'Unexpected result for key: {key}'
```